# Complete mobile version especially the help center

Tags: discussion, feature-request, mobile-web

Will there ever be a full mobile support for Stack Overflow ?

The main page is optimized which is perfect because it makes Asking / Answering easier. With the main page comes the Badges / Tags tabs which are less important pages IMO but anyway they come with it.

My point is the *help* section should be optimized for mobile too. It's one of the most important pages for new users and I'm sure many users like me use the mobile version all the time. It's painful to read the help section on the non-optimized version since you have to scroll left and right and zoom over and over again. Also, when in the help center, you have the old non-optimized tabs above (Questions, Tags, Users, Badgers, Unanswered) that will bring you to the selected pages on the mobile version which makes navigation in the mobile site pretty weird.

### tl;dr

Is there a complete mobile version coming up? Or at least a mobile optimized help center?

Comment: The entire SO site should be optimised for mobile. I attempt to use it on a regular basis but agree that various areas fall short (including _help_).

Comment: Exactly thats why I formulated my title like so. But I put more emphasis on the help center because its one of the last bit to optimize.  Also it looks kinda bad on a "programming" website to not have a mobile version. But thats my opinion though.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd well, we do have fully working app by now.